# Override Windows 10 1903 stereo only sound limit to TV via HDMI

Tags: windows, windows-10, hdmi, tv, surround-sound

How to force Windows 10 1903 to output multichannel audio to a TV via HDMI?

===

For some reason I have to connect my Intel NUC NUC8i3CYSM directly to a TV which is connected to a multichannel AV receiver.

PC->TV connection is HDMI and TV->Receiver connection is HDMI ARC.

The problem is Windows 10 1903 or AMD Radeon RX 540 (I really don't know which one, maybe both) **only outputs 2.0 sound** when connected to a device that reports stereo only audio support for itself, ignoring its passthrough capabilities.

I have of course switched Windows Speaker Setup to 7.1 while it was connected to the receiver but it has switched itself back to stereo as soon as I've reconnected it back to TV.

While my TV is really a stereo only device it successfully outputs any number of channels via HDMI passthrough and I could have a multichannel sound in case I replace the PC with a media player or a game console.

I can also have multichannel sound from PC if I change the connection order to PC->Receiver->TV.

But unfortunately I have to connect the PC to a TV directly.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is doable. I had the similar setup. PC with nVidia GT 710 -->HDMI -->Sony 65" 9000F Series(2018 model) --> ONKYO AVR. I've tried almost every trick that I found through searches and finally returned to previous setup

PC -->HDMI -->ONKYO -->HDMI(ARC) -->TV

& 5.1 surround is again live while playing content through PC. Kind of disappointing when Windows recognizes my TV capable of 5.1 passthrough, however, will not.

Hope this helps